# What is the default timeout for the basichttpbinding in wcf

Tags: wcf, binding, timeout

I am new to wcf, created a service and a consumer. As documentation suggest, default timeout is 10 minutes for ReceiveTimeout.

In consumer side, i tried to reproduce for timeout for the request but event after 25 minutes it works without breaking.

If someone can let me know what exactly the time we can open a channel with basichttp binding?

Below is the wcf app.config:

```
<system.serviceModel>    
      <bindings>
        <basicHttpBinding>
          <binding name="Raj">
            <security mode="Transport">
              <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None" realm="">                
              </transport>
            </security>
          </binding>
        </basicHttpBinding>
      </bindings>      
      <behaviors>
            <serviceBehaviors>
                <behavior name="Raj">
                    <serviceMetadata httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
                    <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
                </behavior>
            </serviceBehaviors>
        </behaviors>   
        <services>
            <service name="WCF_NewsService.News_Service" behaviorConfiguration="Raj">          
                <host>
                    <baseAddresses>
                        <add baseAddress="https://localhost:8732/Design_Time_Addresses/WCF_NewsService/News_Service/"/>
                    </baseAddresses>
                </host>
                <endpoint address="News_Service" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="WCF_NewsService.INews_Service" bindingConfiguration="Raj"/>
            </service>
        </services> 
    </system.serviceModel>
```

**Consumer Code:**

```
    var myBinding = new BasicHttpBinding();
                myBinding.Security.Mode = BasicHttpSecurityMode.Transport;
                myBinding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType =
                HttpClientCredentialType.Certificate;

                myBinding.MaxReceivedMessageSize = Int32.MaxValue;
                myBinding.MaxBufferSize = Int32.MaxValue;

BindingParameterCollection bindingParameters = new BindingParameterCollection();

                var address = new EndpointAddress("https:xxxx:8732/Design_Time_Addresses/WCF_NewsService/News_Service/News_Service");
                                
                ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += (sender, certificate, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true;

                //Client Credentials
                string _thumbPrint = "5AD9BC96AA4D44852D1B97C91C1628C070E3187C";
                ClientCredentials clientCredentials = new ClientCredentials();
                clientCredentials.ClientCertificate.SetCertificate(StoreLocation.LocalMachine, StoreName.My, X509FindType.FindByThumbprint, _thumbPrint);

                bindingParameters.Add(clientCredentials);


                var factory = myBinding.BuildChannelFactory<IRequestChannel>(bindingParameters);
                factory.Open();


                var irc = factory.CreateChannel(address);

                // --- Without body
                Message createRequestMessage = Message.CreateMessage(MessageVersion.Soap11, "http://tempuri.org/INews_Service/Getnews");
                irc.Open();
                var result = irc.Request(createRequestMessage);

                Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(25));


                //--With body
                TOInews tOInews = new TOInews { ID = 125, Body = "this is body test", Header = "This is header test" };
                createRequestMessage = Message.CreateMessage(MessageVersion.Soap11, "http://tempuri.org/INews_Service/GetnewsById", tOInews);
                //irc.Open();
                var result1 = irc.Request(createRequestMessage);
```

Answer (score 1):

[ReceiveTimeout](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.servicemodel.channels.binding.receivetimeout?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0) – used by the Service Framework Layer to initialize the session-idle timeout which controls how long a session can be idle before timing out.
I didn't find that you have `ReceiveTimeout` configured in the config file, you need to configure it.You can see the code below.
You can check the documentation on [how to configure the timeout value on the binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/configuring-timeout-values-on-a-binding).
You can use [Message Inspectors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/samples/message-inspectors) to capture WCF operation execution time. See [this post](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/iis-support-blog/capturing-wcf-request-execution-time/ba-p/287721) for specific steps.

```
 <basicHttpBinding>
          <binding name="Raj" openTimeout="00:10:00"
             closeTimeout="00:10:00"
             sendTimeout="00:10:00"
             receiveTimeout="00:10:00">
            <security mode="Transport">
              <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None" realm="">                
              </transport>
            </security>
          </binding>
        </basicHttpBinding>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  But my question is if we did not mention, what will be the default receiveTimeout? As per documentation, its 10 min but i am able to call even after 10 mins. i had also tried by adding it in app.config, but no use.

Comment: Even after  adding receiveTimeout, its not working. Am i missing any thing?

Comment: The default value of receiveTimeout is 10 minutes. If you want to set a timeout on the client side, configure `SendTimeout`. You can check this documentation on [how to configure the timeout value on the binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/configuring-timeout-values-on-a-binding). Make sure both client and server are configured.